# VPS instance outbound traffic increasing linearly

Tags: tcpdump

I have a DigitalOcean VPS instance whose outbound traffic is behaving strangely, increasing linearly over a 7 day period.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what is going on through `tcpdump`, but to tell the truth I'm not sure what I should be looking for, by doing `tcpdump port not 22` here's a snippet of the kind of traffic that I'm able to see, which looks normal to me:

```
15:48:10.638709 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [S.], seq 262596971, ack 2836813416, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 6], length 0
15:48:10.641314 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 772:1106, ack 41341, win 260, length 334: HTTP: GET /js/pathseg.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.641578 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 41341:44061, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.641616 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 44061:46781, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.641628 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 46781:49501, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.648490 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 351:689, ack 9549, win 260, length 338: HTTP: GET /js/CustomEvent.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.648863 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [P.], seq 9549:10278, ack 689, win 490, length 729: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.651042 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [S], seq 4006037173, win 8192, options [mss 1360,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:48:10.651101 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [S.], seq 153230364, ack 4006037174, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 6], length 0
15:48:10.653203 IP client.yota.ru.57499 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [S], seq 4261651922, win 8192, options [mss 1360,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
15:48:10.653252 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [S.], seq 988269590, ack 4261651923, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 6], length 0
15:48:10.752986 IP 5adddf5b.bb.sky.com.59084 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 97599, win 16179, length 0
15:48:10.787531 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.790883 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.803170 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:366, ack 1, win 260, length 365: HTTP: GET /images/pen-tool.png HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.803239 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], ack 366, win 473, length 0
15:48:10.803626 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [P.], seq 1:696, ack 366, win 473, length 695: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.810546 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:340, ack 1, win 260, length 339: HTTP: GET /js/snap.svg-min.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.810578 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], ack 340, win 473, length 0
15:48:10.810768 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 1:2721, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.810821 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 2721:5441, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.810834 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 5441:8161, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.810846 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 8161:10881, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.810860 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 10881:13601, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.826921 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 44061, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.826976 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 49501:52221, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.869049 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 46781, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.869108 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 52221:54941, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.872426 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 49501, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.872465 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 54941:57661, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.872501 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 57661:59021, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:10.915039 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.931030 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:336, ack 1, win 260, length 335: HTTP: GET /js/TweenMax.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.931088 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], ack 336, win 473, length 0
15:48:10.931446 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 1:2721, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.931484 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 2721:5441, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.931522 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 5441:8161, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.931535 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 8161:10881, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.931576 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 10881:13601, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.949103 IP client.yota.ru.57499 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 260, length 0
15:48:10.955910 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 689:1021, ack 10278, win 257, length 332: HTTP: GET /js/pathd.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.956204 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 10278:12998, ack 1021, win 507, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.956294 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 12998:15718, ack 1021, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.956368 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 15718:18438, ack 1021, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.956438 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 18438:19798, ack 1021, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:10.964088 IP client.yota.ru.57499 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:332, ack 1, win 260, length 331: HTTP: GET /js/husl.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:10.964141 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [.], ack 332, win 473, length 0
15:48:10.964398 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [.], seq 1:2721, ack 332, win 473, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:10.964435 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [.], seq 2721:5441, ack 332, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.964504 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [.], seq 5441:8161, ack 332, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.964531 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [.], seq 8161:10881, ack 332, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:10.964634 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57499: Flags [P.], seq 10881:12010, ack 332, win 473, length 1129: HTTP
15:48:10.978964 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 138241, win 4051, options [nop,nop,TS val 233878770 ecr 177968374], length 0
15:48:10.979015 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > 86.99.240.61.57642: Flags [.], seq 184321:187201, ack 325, win 470, options [nop,nop,TS val 177968541 ecr 233878770], length 2880: HTTP
15:48:10.979056 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 139681, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233878773 ecr 177968374], length 0
15:48:11.030471 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 2721, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.030549 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 13601:16321, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.030581 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 16321:19041, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.036128 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 366:745, ack 696, win 257, length 379: HTTP: GET /js/dom.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:11.036412 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 696:3416, ack 745, win 490, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:11.036491 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 3416:4776, ack 745, win 490, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.036600 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [P.], seq 4776:4794, ack 745, win 490, length 18: HTTP
15:48:11.072690 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 5441, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.072745 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 19041:21761, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.072845 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 21761:24481, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.073498 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 5441, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {6801:8161}], length 0
15:48:11.075665 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 8161, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.075697 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 24481:27201, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.146475 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.146527 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 27201:29921, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.146662 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 29921:31281, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.172332 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 50861, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {52221:53581}], length 0
15:48:11.172408 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 59021:61741, ack 1106, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.203150 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 2721, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.203229 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 13601:16321, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.203265 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 16321:19041, ack 336, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.207504 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 141121, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233879138 ecr 177968393], length 0
15:48:11.207542 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > 86.99.240.61.57642: Flags [.], seq 187201:190081, ack 325, win 470, options [nop,nop,TS val 177968598 ecr 233879138], length 2880: HTTP
15:48:11.231921 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 12998, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.231999 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 19798:22518, ack 1021, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.281171 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 14358, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.281231 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 22518:23878, ack 1021, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.302634 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.302715 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 9521:10881, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.306229 IP client.yota.ru.57499 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 1361, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.310603 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 2 {16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.310648 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 10881:12241, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.318232 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 2056, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {4776:4794}], length 0
15:48:11.356646 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 3 {24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.356732 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 12241:13601, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.364536 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 4 {27201:28561}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.364576 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 14961:16321, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.368498 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 2056:3416, ack 745, win 490, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.368541 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 3416:4776, ack 745, win 490, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.389609 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 4 {27201:29921}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.389678 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 17681:19041, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.393510 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 9521, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 4 {27201:31281}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.393547 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 19041:20401, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.433266 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 50861, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 2 {59021:60381}{52221:53581}], length 0
15:48:11.433327 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 50861:52221, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.437279 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 50861, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 2 {59021:61741}{52221:53581}], length 0
15:48:11.437313 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 53581:54941, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.468139 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 2721, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {14961:16321}], length 0
15:48:11.468214 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 2721:4081, ack 336, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.473031 IP client.yota.ru.57500 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 2721, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {14961:17681}], length 0
15:48:11.473067 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57500: Flags [.], seq 4081:5441, ack 336, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.506463 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 14358, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {19798:21158}], length 0
15:48:11.506527 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 14358:15718, ack 1021, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.512449 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 14358, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {19798:22518}], length 0
15:48:11.512488 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 15718:17078, ack 1021, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.533685 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 141121, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233879378 ecr 177968393,nop,nop,sack 1 {142561:144001}], length 0
15:48:11.533778 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > 86.99.240.61.57642: Flags [.], seq 190081:191521, ack 325, win 470, options [nop,nop,TS val 177968680 ecr 233879378], length 1440: HTTP
15:48:11.533805 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 141121, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233879378 ecr 177968393,nop,nop,sack 1 {142561:145441}], length 0
15:48:11.550526 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 141121, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233879542 ecr 177968393,nop,nop,sack 1 {142561:146881}], length 0
15:48:11.550579 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > 86.99.240.61.57642: Flags [.], seq 141121:142561, ack 325, win 470, options [nop,nop,TS val 177968684 ecr 233879542], length 1440: HTTP
15:48:11.550660 IP 86.99.240.61.57642 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 141121, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 233879555 ecr 177968393,nop,nop,sack 1 {142561:148321}], length 0
15:48:11.550693 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > 86.99.240.61.57642: Flags [.], seq 191521:192961, ack 325, win 470, options [nop,nop,TS val 177968684 ecr 233879555], length 1440: HTTP
15:48:11.551623 IP client.yota.ru.57494 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 14358, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {19798:23878}], length 0
15:48:11.551666 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57494: Flags [.], seq 17078:18438, ack 1021, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.558619 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 10881, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 4 {27201:31281}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.558665 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 20401:21761, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.558698 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 21761:23121, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.594606 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 12241, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 4 {27201:31281}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}{13601:14961}], length 0
15:48:11.594682 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 23121:24481, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.594718 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 25841:27201, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.624575 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 14961, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 3 {27201:31281}{24481:25841}{16321:17681}], length 0
15:48:11.624659 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 31281:34001, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.630549 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 17681, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 2 {27201:31281}{24481:25841}], length 0
15:48:11.630598 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 34001:36721, ack 340, win 473, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.633155 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 3416, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {4776:4794}], length 0
15:48:11.639232 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 4794, win 260, length 0
15:48:11.676161 IP client.yota.ru.57497 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [P.], seq 745:1129, ack 4794, win 260, length 384: HTTP: GET /js/tutorial.js HTTP/1.1
15:48:11.676557 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 4794:7514, ack 1129, win 507, length 2720: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:48:11.676677 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 7514:10234, ack 1129, win 507, length 2720: HTTP
15:48:11.676751 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [.], seq 10234:11594, ack 1129, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.676868 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57497: Flags [P.], seq 11594:12190, ack 1129, win 507, length 596: HTTP
15:48:11.680542 IP client.yota.ru.57498 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 17681, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 3 {19041:20401}{27201:31281}{24481:25841}], length 0
15:48:11.680592 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57498: Flags [.], seq 36721:38081, ack 340, win 473, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.684191 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 53581, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {59021:61741}], length 0
15:48:11.684230 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 54941:56301, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.684260 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 56301:57661, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.707213 IP client.yota.ru.57493 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [.], ack 54941, win 260, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {59021:61741}], length 0
15:48:11.707278 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 57661:59021, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.707382 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > client.yota.ru.57493: Flags [.], seq 61741:63101, ack 1106, win 507, length 1360: HTTP
15:48:11.717599 IP c-73-129-30-55.hsd1.md.comcast.net.59209 > ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http: Flags [S], seq 2279888157, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 380938937 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
15:48:11.717671 IP ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01.http > c-73-129-30-55.hsd1.md.comcast.net.59209: Flags [S.], seq 2491122979, ack 2279888158, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 177968726 ecr 380938937,nop,wscale 6], length 0
```

I'm lost as to be able to diagnose the source of this traffic, can anybody offer more pointers as to find the source of this traffic?

Comment: Check your `nginx` access log and see what IP's are visiting you site most frequently.

Comment: @Tanmay nginx log looks fairly normal to me, I have a bit of traffic but I don't understand why it's increasing like this.

Comment: Looking at the graphs, the most probable case is that this is HTTP traffic maybe because your website is getting more users. If you think that's not the case, install some monitoring software to find out which process is using most bandwidth.

Comment: `tcpdump`'s dump won't help because it is showing traffic of a small time period.

Comment: There are tools for analyzing access logs and seeing who is downloading what and how many times.  There are too many to name and that is a broad subject.  Hopefully you also log referers.